# ARToolkit: Created new .pat file doesn't work

Tags: android, artoolkit

I'm using ARToolkit in my Android project. I used [this](http://www.artoolworks.com/support/library/Creating_and_training_new_ARToolKit_markers) to help me create a new marker and everything worked fine. The file created was called marker64.pat. However, the standard pattern files that ARToolkit uses are .patt files (with the extra t). Why did it create a .pat file for me?

This .pat file doesn't seem to work, as it crashes my application just as it starts.

This is the original line of code that was already there (which works fine):

```
markerID = ARToolKit.getInstance().addMarker("single;Data/hiro.patt;80");
```

This is my changed version:

```
markerID = ARToolKit.getInstance().addMarker("single;Data/marker64.pat;80");
```

This is my marker image whilst I'm creating the marker:

[image]

Can you please let me know why, firstly, my file was created as .pat file and not a .patt file. And secondly, why this file doesn't work if it's correct.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, no idea why it was called pat instead of patt. But regarding your issue. Did you take care that while creating the marker the red corner was in the top left area. Also how big is your marker? Does it have 80mm from left to right and how big are the borders? Additionally, can you maybe share your marker image?

Comment: @Thor_Bux hi there, I've edited the question to show the marker image before I click Create Marker

Comment: Hi @Rafill thanks for editing your question.

The thing is that the Android logo is symmetric along the vertical axis. I think markers need to be unique along the horizontal and the vertical axis in order to recognize and track correctly.
https://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=3_Marker_Training:marker_training
But I'm not entirely sure about that, maybe you can generate a marker with s different pattern to try.

Comment: Hi @Thor_Bux i tried using a different image. An eagle in this case, but it still didn't work